# Error after moving website on localhost: Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect

Tags: php, yii

I'm completly new in YII. I was asked by my friend to add some functions to his website. I wanted to copy the website on my localhost to make a working copy. I get errors which I don't understand. Today is the third day of googling and finally I decided to add new topic the forum :-)

You can [see the errors here](http://latech.pl/yii/yii-increment.htm)

I believe [this solution](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11727-fine-on-localhost-fatal-error-on-live-server-why/page__p__57457__hl__indirect+modification#entry57457) could help some way, but I even don't know where to put those two lines:

```
$rating = $model->rating;

$rating = array_pop($rating);
```

I'll be grateful for any comments and tips.

Regards,
Bernard

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Yii, but most of the time you have to modify the path when going from local to production. Make sure you have your paths setup correctly in config. I would start here and make sure you have the minimum requirements to run YII locally. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I check all DB and the code several times - I don't have any direct links. I modified `.htaccess` file with my local path. I can'tgo to another page, because I get 404 erroe. I'll try installing a new website steb by step. Maybe I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : Well, I was wrong, take a look here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#bindParam-detail

You have to [pass your var by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), and you cannot do this with [Yii::app()->session](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#session-detail) since it is an [overloaded property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get).

As you said in your comment, you can simply use [bindValue](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#bindValue-detail).

Comment: Hi soju,Your tip didn't help.

Comment: I've read somewhere that I should change `bindParam` to `bindValue`. The error doesn't show, but another does: Trying to get property of non-object. The line with the error: `$basketCookies = Yii::app()->request->cookies['basket' . Yii::app()->user->userId]->value;`. I tried finding which one isn't object, but I don't know. However, I checked the version of YII - 1.1.8 from 2011, so I guess it's high time to upgrade. But I still wonder, why it work on server and doesn't work on localhost. I'll investigate once again, maybe I'll find something new. Thanks again,.

Comment: Answer updated. What is your php version on your localhost server ?

Comment: Hi soju again. I figure out what caused the errors. Yes, errors, because there were a lot of them. My xampp has enabled error displaying. The first one was related to YII and the function which I mentioned about. Many of others were mistakes of programmers. For instance, getting a cookie without checking if it exists. Now the app on my localhost works perfect. Once again I'd like to thank you for your time. No

Comment: About php version and your comment which I hadn't seen when I wrote my comment. I checked everything. I compared `phpinfo` results from localhost and the server. I didn't want to update YII, because I believed (and I was right), it should work on localhost if it works on the server. Sometimes it's good to say to yourself: hold on, let's start from the beginning...